Update UTCDateTimeAttribute attribute in PynamoDB based on conditon
I have a PynamoDB (v6.0.0) model defined as:
class ArticleModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        table_name = "TABLE_NAME"

    id = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True)
    article = MapAttribute()
    created_at = UTCDateTimeAttribute(default_for_new=datetime.now(timezone.utc))
    last_modified_at = UTCDateTimeAttribute(default_for_new=datetime.now(timezone.utc))

I'm performing batch operations (batch.save and batch.delete) on the table using ArticleModel  as shown below:
with ArticleModel.batch_write() as batch:
    for identifier, article_data in article_dict["add_or_update"]:
        item = ArticleModel(id=identifier, article=article_data)
        batch.save(item)
    for identifier in article_dict["delete"]:
        item = ArticleModel(id=identifier)
        batch.delete(item)

The table already has a few items in it. When I try to update these items using batch both the created_at attribute and last_modified_at attribute are getting updated with the latest datetime.
Can you please help me with:

How do I make sure that created_at is only assigned once when the new item is added?
How do I keep updating the last_modified_at attribute each time there is some change in the item?


Batch operations in PynamoDB, which utilize BatchWriteItem from boto3 under the hood, present a challenge when it comes to updating existing items in DynamoDB tables. The behavior of BatchWriteItem (according to docs) dictates that existing items are replaced with new ones, meaning that attributes like created_at will be overwritten each time an item is updated, resulting in the behavior observed above.
The only solution for this would be to manually check (using scan operation) if created_at is already set before adding a new item. If it's not set, we can assign the current datetime. Otherwise, we leave it unchanged.
